# RFM95 in LoRa mode with STM32F103 - I can't transmit and receive anything

Tags: arduino, stm32, lora

I'm using RFM95 on LoRa mode with STM32F103. My code is very simple, I'm just using the controller as a "bridge" between serial and SPI.

```cpp
if (Serial.available()>0) {
  inByte = Serial.read();
  if(fifao==0) {
    if (inByte=='R') {
      //if we send R to the serial port it will print all registers values --- it is all working here
      imprimeregist();
    } else if (inByte=='r') {
      //if we send r to the serial port it will read all fifo addres from 0 to 0x80 and print it in the screen --- it is all working here
      lefifo();
    } else if(inByte=='F') {
      //if we send F to the serial port it will read the fifo address and return the value--- it is all working here
      Serial.println(F("type fifo address please: "));
      fifao=1;
    } else {
      //if we type any other thing it will write the next typed value to the address specified 
      entrada[contser]=inByte;
      contser++;
    }
  } else {
    fifu=inByte; 
    Serial.println(spiRcv(fifu),HEX);
    fifao=0;
  }
  if(contser==2) {
    //writing the value ---------------- it is working here too
    writeSPI(entrada[0],entrada[1]);
    Serial.println( spiRead(entrada[0]),HEX);
    contser=0;
  }
```

I'm using the Arduino IDE (I used a lot of software and got to the same place). I just can't transmit.

I wrote the registers in one of them to RX LoRa mode and in the other one to TX LoRa mode.

Can anybody help me? Maybe with the values of the registers I have to use or the way I have to do for transmitting and receiving data.

Comment: congrats friend. i'm not asking for the code. I know the code thing, don't need help on this. i'm asking about the radio. I use the IDE cause the radio library they gave is for arduino, i had the controller and start using it. if you don't want to help or even read the question why the hell do you comment?
BTW, i'll not use the IDE after knowing how to make the radio work, and what registers I have to set for my usage.

Comment: Firstly I'm not your friend. Secondly go to the place where people use those "great" libraries https://arduino.stackexchange.com/. I gave you the correct hint. You are just rude

Comment: Oh you didn't get my question. I really need help with the radio and its registers. Thanks for the hint, but they can't help me there, i'm just really sick of this libraries and the IDE. Sorry for been rude. I'm reading the manual and trying setting the registers. it just doesn't work. I called the hope suport here in Brazil and they  don't know anything about the radio, "use arduino and the rfm95 library for it"  was their hint for me. But thanks anyway. I'm going to meet the SmartCompose  CEO tomorrow (they sell hope radios here) and if  he  doesn't help me i'm going to search for other  rad

Comment: @EliasMurad I don't get your question. What does not work? Did you set the chip into the LoRa mode? Did you set equal carrier frequency on transmitter and receiver side? Did you set the modem parameters accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I called hope suport here in Brazil and they told me how to set everything. The problem is, the radio didnt work, i think  I didnt get how to send words. Now i can send only one byte. And if I change the packet lenght it stops sending things. The TX done flag  stops  too so i think the problem is with the transmitter

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce interference, Lora node radios use I/Q inversion on receive in order to hear only the Gateway and not each other.

In order for two Lora nodes to talk to each other directly, their invert IQ flags need to be cleared (as seen here https://github.com/things-nyc/arduino-lmic/blob/master/src/lmic/radio.c#L590)

```
#define LORARegInvertIQ 0x33
writeReg(LORARegInvertIQ, readReg(LORARegInvertIQ) & ~(1<<6));
```

Once you do that they should be able to hear each other. Here's sample Arduino sketch that does it: https://github.com/things-nyc/arduino-lmic/blob/master/examples/raw/raw.ino

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, Looks like the radio was not working right too...
They sent me another one and i'm starting using it today.